# Create JIRA issue from Outlook email

Tags: outlook, jira, jira-plugin

Is it possible to automatically create JIRA issue from some pre-defined Outlook email ? So as soon as that configured mail id receives any mail, a JIRA issue is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/creating-issues-and-comments-from-email-802592933.html

But the creator of the issue created with the mail won't get any notifications I think. you would have to create a custom plugin and use that plugin to notify mails entered in the new custom field.

See https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/creating-a-custom-mail-handler-for-jira/ for working with mail handlers

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i just made my incoming email with automatic create an issue and response back an email to the sender.

you need to have SIL plug in first to make it all possible

then you should configure your incoming email as POP/IMAP

after configuring it there is this getIncomingEmail() routine in SIL that retrieve's all the email received by the POP/IMAP server.

then here is the create issue routine createIssue()

after creating the issue you can now use the sendEmail() Routine to response back to the sender that you received his/her query/email.

check this link it will helps you a lot in learning SIL: https://confluence.cprime.io/display/SIL

if you still need help just let me know. thanks